# how to make filter work on column its values are array of object in MUIDataTable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-fullstack, mui-datatable

```
const columns = [
      {
            name: "technologies",
            label: "Technologies",
            options: {
                filter: true,
                sort: false,
                empty: true,
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
                    return (
                        <div>{value && value.map((v) => v.name + ", ")}</div>
                    );
                },
            },
        },
]
```

this code I wrote for this column, when I run program and try to use filter for this column  filter was object

note : we get technologies from database in this form

```
[{id:"REACT",name:"react js"},{id:"CPP",name:"c++"},{id:"TYPESCRIPT",name:"typescript"}]
```

I want show in this column only name and filter on it.
sorry I am not good in English and this first time to use stake overflow.

Comment: I solved it by changing data in useEffect as I wanted

Comment: Hi Sarah, like an array?

Answer (score 0):

This is also my first time answering a question on stack overflow, but I happened to just be working on something similar to this. I hope this answer helps you :)

```
const columns = createColumns(tableData);
  const createColumns = (tableData) => {
    return [
      {
        name: 'technologies',
        label: 'Technologies',
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: false,
          empty: true,
          customBodyRenderLite: (index) => {
            const values = tableData[index];
            return values?.map((v, i) => values.length - 1 > i ? v.name + ", " : v.name);
          },
        },
      },
    ];
  };
```